# Laravel get all User information in relation ship method

Tags: laravel

in User and Post models i'm create simple RelationShip as an:

Posts model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

User model:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Posts');
}
```

create new item in database i have `user_id` such as `1` in posts table. after using this code into controller :

```
$all_records = \App\Posts::all();
```

i dont have user_id information in posts table. for example user_id in posts table is `1` and i want to have sub query as an all user table where id is 1

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
$all_records = \App\Posts::with('user')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all posts where user_id is 1, then you could say:

`User::find(1)->posts`;